# Remove django sites app

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

I'd like to know if I can just ditch the `Sites` default app (comment it out from `INSTALLED_APPS` and so on) without breaking anything?

It's written in the doc that some other parts of django use it (redirects framework, comments, flatpages, syndic, auth, shortcut and view on site), but it's not explicitly said if it's going to break them. Is it?

Django 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that there are not any dependencies from some other files in your project or in your apps you can safely remove them. 
First comment out one by one and every time check the project in your browser if it is running correctly. Also check the logs for warnings and errors.